# When serving .dmg files from PHP, user is getting 'disk image not recognized'

Tags: php, iis, mime, dmg

I have a `.dmg` file on my IIS server. When downloading directly the file opens just fine, but when I serve the file via PHP like so

```
$mime_types['dmg']   ='application/x-apple-diskimage';
$filename = getfile($_GET['dc']);           
$fakename = fakefilename($_GET['dc']);
$extension = fileexten($filename);
    if(($filename!= false)&&($fakename!=false&& @fopen($filename,'r')==true)){
    $mime = contenttype($extension);
    set_time_limit(0);
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Expires: 0'); 
    header("Content-Type:".$mime);
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='.$fakename.'.'.$extension);
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
      if (ob_get_length() > 0) {
        ob_end_clean();
        }
    flush();
    @readfile($filename);
    }
```

I get an error on the mac saying 'disk image not recognized'
I've also tried setting the .dmg application/octet-stream but I still run into the same issue.

Comment: flush before readfile? also you may have to use ob_flash too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that that this is either a case in which the content type is not set correctly or in which the content length is incorrectly set. Check to see if `$mime = contenttype($extension);` returns the correct content type.

It would be useful to debug this with a web debugging proxy tool (like Fiddler or Charles) and post the entire response header, when accessing the file directly & when you access it via your PHP script.

**UPDATE (based on the comments below):**

The script had additional line breaks at the end of the file, which were being sent out in the response.

Comment: `HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: public
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/x-apple-diskimage
Expires: 0
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.11
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=AcrobatXPro.dmg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 18 Sep 2014 15:50:06 GMT` is the header I get from downloading via php

Comment: Please also post the headers for the direct download. Also, please do an `md5 checksum` (see md5_file in PHP) on both files (direct & the one you get from PHP) to make sure you actually get the same content in both cases (e.g. there isn't any additional data that's being injected by the PHP script in the output).

Comment: For the direct download `Accept-Ranges: "bytes" Content-Length" 497415912" Content-Type: "application/x-apple-diskimage" Etag: "80603b1eb3fecb1:0" Server: "Microsoft-IIS/8.5" And you're right additional data is being injected by the PHP script. The md5 checksum does not match up

Comment: As the content doesn't match, you'll need to figure out what's generating the difference (either PHP notices/warnings/errors being added to the content if you have display_errors on, or new lines at the end of your file if you close the PHP script with `?>`, etc.).

Comment: You were right! There were two line breaks at the end of the script. Removing it worked!